# Mongoose isn't validating a model using the builtin validator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm running Mongoose 3.8.8 and am having trouble trying to get it to enforce the built-in validation rules against a property of my model.

I have the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Drink Schema
 */
var DrinkSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: "{PATH} is required."},
    description: String,
    sku: {type: String, required: "{PATH} is required."},
    contains: String,
    count: { type: Number, min: 0 }
});

mongoose.model('Drink', DrinkSchema);
```

When I insert a drink with a negative count (via `Drink.update({sku:sku}, {name:name, count: -1}, {upsert:true}, callback);`) I am met with success.  Querying the database confirms that the document insertion was permitted.

I'm new to this ecosystem, so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, it looks to be a dupe. For some reason, search failed me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Validation is an internal [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) which doesn't get called on `Model.update`. If you want validations to run on update, you need the find the document, update the attributes and save it. Like in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html):

```
Tank.findById(id, function (err, tank) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  tank.size = 'large';
  tank.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.send(tank);
  });
});
```